# Function to replace key/value strings between brackets with custom html

Tags: javascript, regex, logic

Say I have a string like this:

`Hello World, here are the links to {my Twitter: https://twitter.com/twitter} and to {Google: https://google.com}`

I'm trying to write a function that replaces the `{Title: url}` with a html element, to return this:

`Hello world, here are the links to <a href="twitter.com/twitter">my Twitter</a> and to <a href="https://google.com>Google</a>`

what I've come up with so far is

```
function processWithRegex(string) {
  let links = []
  let regex = /[^{\}]+(?=})/g
  let matches = string.match(regex)
  matches.forEach((match) => {
    match = match.split(': ')
    links.push(match)
  })
  links.forEach((link) => {
    html = `<a href='${link[1]}'>${link[0]}</a>`
    console.log(html)
  })
  return string
}
```

which, obviously, returns the input string, but at least `console.log`s correct html elements. My brain is giving up and I would really appreciate some help… Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of JavaScript's [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) function. Since you want to replace each `{txt: link}` occurrence, you can create a regular expression which matches this pattern and groups everything between the `{` and `}`. Using the callback for the `.replace()` method, you can then `.split(': ')` to get the text and the link components, which you can then return as part of a link:

```js
function processWithRegex(string) {
  let regex = /\{([^\}]*)\}/g;
  let new_str = string.replace(regex, (_,m) => {
    const [txt, link] = m.split(': ');
    return `<a href="${link}">${txt}</a>`;
  });
  return new_str;
}

const to_parse = "Hello World, here are the links to {my Twitter: https://twitter.com/twitter} and to {Google: https://google.com}";
const parsed = processWithRegex(to_parse);
console.log(parsed);

document.body.innerHTML = parsed;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! could you maybe explain what the `(_,m)` is? i understand what the function is doing, but the underscore puzzles me a bit…

Comment: also amazed by `const [txt, link] = m.split(': ');`, I didn't know this was possible 

Comment: @bruno sure, no worries. The `(_, m)` is part of the arrow function's arguments in the callback to replace. You can think of it as `function(_, m) {...}`. The first argument to replace's callback is the entire match the regex matches on (this include the `{` and `}` in it). The second argument (`m`) is the first capture group in the regex (so everything between `{` and `}`). As I don't want the `{` and `}` in the string which I split, I ignore the first argument (I could have named it anything such as `foo` - but `_` is typically used for unused arguments).

Comment: @bruno as for the `const [txt, link] = ...` that's known as [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) - definitely worth looking into as it has many nice use cases